# meteor modifing html class tags

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui

I noticed something very strange (and annoying): whenever there is a variable in a meteor template, class tags are rewritten.

Example with the default meteor app, modifying only the "hello" template:

```
   <template name="hello">
     <button class="middle aligned center aligned">Click Me {{counter}}</button>
     <button class="middle aligned center aligned">Click Me</button>
     <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
   </template>
```

You will notice that in the "class" tag, there is "aligned" twice, it is very usefull when using semantic-ui (taken from one of the examples: http://semantic-ui.com/examples/login.html)

when the page load, if you go to the developer tools, you will see this:

```
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  <button class="middle aligned center">Click Me 0</button>
  <button class="middle aligned center aligned">Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button 0 times.</p>
</body>
```

one of the "aligned" tags have disappeared.

So my question is: **is it possible to tell meteor to not modify class tags**?

Thanks

Comment: I'm really do not understand why you use both 'middle aligned' and 'center aligned'.

Comment: Check the example link I gave, it is because the login textbox must be aligned both horizontally (center) and vertically (middle).

Comment: I see, in this case I think I'll wrap it with 2 div :D.
`<div class="middle aligned"><div class="center aligned"></div></div>`

Comment: yes, that's what I ended up doing, but it's gonna take me a lot of time if I have to do that every time I use some code from an example.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor removes bad css declarations. That second *aligned* tag is redundant and you should remove it anyway. If *middle aligned* is different than *center aligned* then you should have two different classes, ex: *middle-aligned* and *center-aligned*.

Comment: But why does it do that only on some items and not all?
As for changing the class names, I can't, it's part of semantic-ui

Comment: That's a darn good question and a possible bug. It should remove them everywhere. I know that when I've had typos in my css Meteor has just removed the offending attributes.